# html and css webpage content resize

Tags: html, css, resize

THis is my first time commenting on this website. I've found this site to be helpful in the past but now I can't seem to find a solution to my problem to I would like for someone to answer me directly.

I have webpage using where I have a fixed header and footer and absolute positioned panel where the content goes. My problem is, when I resize the browser the header content stays in the fixed position> Now that is obvious, none the less I would like to have it move with the scroll of the rest of the page. When I set the header to relative, it does work to my liking, but then the header nav links go under my lowerband and z-indexing wouldn't help. The same goes for the footer. 
Also for the content panel, when I set the body overflow to auto or show, the content panel when I scroll, leaves a whitespace to the right. 
Can anyone help me with this problem? It is very frustrating. 
And one more thing, can anyone help me with code to use for css for my ux-header-upperbandcontent and lowebandcontent?. I would like to place the logo and other text in the upperband and the nav links in the lowerband but using a content wrapper.

Thanks. Here is my code for css and html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--BACKGROUND-->

<!--HOME--> 
<div id="home">
</div>
<!--ABOUT-->
<div id="about" class="panel">
<div class="content">
<p>about content</p>


</div>
</div>
<!--SERVICES-->
<div id="services" class="panel">
<div class="content">
<p>services content</p>


</div>


</div>
<!--CONTACT-->
<div id="contact" class="panel">
<div class="content">
<p>contact content</p>


</div>
</div>
<!--HEADER-->

<div id="ux-header">
<div id="ux-header" class="upperband">
</div>
<div id="ux-header" class="lowerband">
</div>
<div id="ux-header">
<ul id="ux-header" class="dev-navigation">
<li><a id="dev-home" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li><a id="dev-services" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a id="dev-about" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a id="dev-contact" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>


<!--FOOTER-->
<div id="ux-footer">    
</div>
</body>
</html>




body {
min-width:980px;
margin: 0px; 
color: rgb(51, 51, 51); 
line-height: 30px; 
font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica",Garuda,Arial,sans-serif; 
font-size: 0.81em; 
cursor: default; 
overflow:hidden;
}
a {
color: rgb(0, 68, 204);
text-decoration: none; 
cursor: pointer;
}
img {
border:currentColor; 
border-image: none; 
max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
}
ol {
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
}
li {
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
}
p {
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
}
ul {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul li {
margin-bottom: 0px; 
margin-left: 15px;
}
ol li {
margin-bottom: 2px; 
margin-left: 18px;
}
p {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1 {
margin: 0px; 
color:rgb(104, 33, 122); 
font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
margin: 0px; 
color:rgb(104, 33, 122); 
font-weight: normal;
}
h3 {
margin: 0px; 
color:rgb(104, 33, 122); 
font-weight: normal;
}
h1 {
line-height: 42px; 
font-size: 2.77em; 
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1.error {
margin-top: 50px;
}
h2 {
line-height: 34px; 
font-size: 2.16em; 
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h3 {
line-height: 24px;
font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold","Segoe UI",Tahoma,"Microsoft Sans Serif",Verdana,sans-serif; 
font-size: 1.39em; 
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h4 {
margin: 0px 0px 10px; 
color: rgb(51, 51, 51); 
line-height: 20px; 
font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold","Segoe UI",Tahoma,"Microsoft Sans Serif",Verdana,sans-serif; 
font-size: 1.08em;
}   
#ux-header.dev-navigation {
margin-top:60px;
width:300px;    
z-index:3;
left:70%;
white-space:nowrap;
}
#ux-header .dev-navigation li{
padding-right:10px;
margin:10px;
}
#ux-header ul.dev-navigation li{
display:inline;
}
#ux-header.dev-navigation li a {
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:12px;
padding-bottom:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
#ux-header.dev-navigation li a:hover {
padding-bottom:3px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:#4169E1;
border-bottom-width:10px;
}
#ux-header {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
z-index:2000;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#ux-header a {
color:#FFF;
}
#ux-header ul {
margin:0px;
}
#ux-header li {
margin:0px;
}
#ux-header .upperband{
height:60px;
background-color:#000;  
}
#ux-header.upperbandcontent {
margin:0px, auto;
padding:0px, 10px;
width:100%;
max-width:980px;
}
#ux-header .lowerband {
top:60px;
height:30px;
background-color:#F42;
}
#ux-header.lowerbandcontent {
position:absolute;
margin:0px, 0px, 5px, 0px;
padding:0px, 10px;
width:100%;
max-width:980px;
}
#ux-footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#000;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:8px;
border-top-color:#0000FF;
z-index:2000;
}
.content {
font-size:12px;
padding:3px;
line-height:10px;
color:#fff;
display:inline-block;
margin:3px 0px;
z-index:-1;
}
.content h2{
font-size: 30px;
padding: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
margin-top: 52px;
color: #fff;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.content p{
font-size: 12px;
padding: 3px;
line-height: 16px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
margin: 3px 0px;
}
.panel {
position:absolute;
min-width:100%;
min-height:80%;
margin-top:90px;
right:2000px;
background-color:#FF00FF;
z-index:-2;
transition:right 2s;
overflow:hidden;
}
.panel:target {
background-color:#F6A600;
right:0;      
}
#home:target ~ #ux-header .dev-navigation #dev-home,
#about:target ~ #ux-header .dev-navigation #dev-about,
#services:target ~ #ux-header .dev-navigation #dev-services,
#contact:target ~ #ux-header .dev-navigation #dev-contact,{
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble posting it, It is there now.

Comment: Im thinking that I can use a java script, that when the header size goes below a certain width, it would change into a menu style naviation and the footer contents as well. But for the content, on the homepage I would have a video and that may pose problems?.

Comment: i have given you a fiddle as your question was not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/huawb/

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
/* grid4 */
.col {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    clear: none !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that response, but it is quite not what I wanted. What I meant was when I resize my browser width, my content is hidden. When I set my body overflow to scroll or auto the content area/panel will scroll left or right which is what I want, but however there is a whitespace to the right of the panel/content area when you scroll due to the resize width.

Comment: provide a fiddle so i can understand

Comment: this is my fiddle after the changes you did..you need to click the update fiddle

Comment: sorry about that. here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/VFc3T/4/   and this is somewhat what I am looking for http://wearespry.com/case-studies/   I would like to have my content do exactly what this site does and the nav elements. My problem however is that I do not know any javascript whatsoever! all resizing problems